# Android Maps V2 Application Crashes on Phone

Tags: java, android, api, maps

I've used my app on my phone(Samsung Galaxy S3, 4.1.2) as people adviced me to when it comes to android map v2 apps but I still get the same error where it says that my app has unfortuntely stopped.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.name;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SupportMapFragment fragment = new SupportMapFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(android.R.id.content, fragment).commit();
    }
}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.name"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
        android:debuggable="true" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.name.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="**api_key**" />
    </application>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

</manifest>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

**Logcat**

```
03-04 00:26:51.274: E/dalvikvm(14369): Could not find class 'com.google.android.maps.MapView', referenced from method com.cornboyzmaps.googlemapsA.MainActivity.onCreate

03-04 00:26:51.279: W/dalvikvm(14369): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 465 (Lcom/google/android/maps/MapView;) in Lcom/cornboyzmaps/googlemapsA/MainActivity;

03-04 00:26:51.279: D/dalvikvm(14369): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0014

03-04 00:26:51.279: D/dalvikvm(14369): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x0cdf at 0x34 in Lcom/cornboyzmaps/googlemapsA/MainActivity;.onCreate

03-04 00:26:51.344: D/AndroidRuntime(14369): Shutting down VM

03-04 00:26:51.344: W/dalvikvm(14369): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x413832a0)

03-04 00:26:51.354: E/AndroidRuntime(14369): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

03-04 00:26:51.354: E/AndroidRuntime(14369): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cornboyzmaps.googlemapsA/com.cornboyzmaps.googlemapsA.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment

03-04 00:26:51.354: E/AndroidRuntime(14369):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)

03-04 00:26:51.354: E/AndroidRuntime(14369):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)

03-04 00:26:51.354: E/AndroidRuntime(14369):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)

03-04 00:26:51.354: E/AndroidRuntime(14369):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)

03-04 00:26:51.354: E/AndroidRuntime(14369):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

03-04 00:26:51.354: E/AndroidRuntime(14369):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

03-04 00:26:51.354: E/AndroidRuntime(14369):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)

03-04 00:26:51.354: E/AndroidRuntime(14369):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

03-04 00:26:51.354: E/AndroidRuntime(14369):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

03-04 00:26:51.354: E/AndroidRuntime(14369):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)

03-04 00:26:51.354: E/AndroidRuntime(14369):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)

03-04 00:26:51.354: E/AndroidRuntime(14369):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

03-04 00:26:51.354: E/AndroidRuntime(14369): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment

03-04 00:26:51.354: E/AndroidRuntime(14369):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)

03-04 00:26:51.354: E/AndroidRuntime(14369):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)

03-04 00:26:51.354: E/AndroidRuntime(14369):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)

03-04 00:26:51.354: E/AndroidRuntime(14369):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)

03-04 00:26:51.354: E/AndroidRuntime(14369):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)

03-04 00:26:51.354: E/AndroidRuntime(14369):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:308)

03-04 00:26:51.354: E/AndroidRuntime(14369):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1924)

03-04 00:26:51.354: E/AndroidRuntime(14369):    at com.cornboyzmaps.googlemapsA.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)

03-04 00:26:51.354: E/AndroidRuntime(14369):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)

03-04 00:26:51.354: E/AndroidRuntime(14369):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)

03-04 00:26:51.354: E/AndroidRuntime(14369):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)

03-04 00:26:51.354: E/AndroidRuntime(14369):    ... 11 more

03-04 00:26:51.354: E/AndroidRuntime(14369): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public

03-04 00:26:51.354: E/AndroidRuntime(14369):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:584)

03-04 00:26:51.354: E/AndroidRuntime(14369):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:552)

03-04 00:26:51.354: E/AndroidRuntime(14369):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4849)

03-04 00:26:51.354: E/AndroidRuntime(14369):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)

03-04 00:26:51.354: E/AndroidRuntime(14369):    ... 21 more

03-04 00:26:51.354: E/AndroidRuntime(14369): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment

03-04 00:26:51.354: E/AndroidRuntime(14369):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)

03-04 00:26:51.354: E/AndroidRuntime(14369):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)

03-04 00:26:51.354: E/AndroidRuntime(14369):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)

03-04 00:26:51.354: E/AndroidRuntime(14369):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:574)

03-04 00:26:51.354: E/AndroidRuntime(14369):    ... 24 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, you are missing the code for the Maps V2 library in your project. You need to correctly attach to the Android library project representing the Play Services SDK. See [the Play Services documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html), specifically the part beginning with "To set up a project to use the Google Play services SDK".

Comment: It's i've already done it before getting this error, and i've checked this right now and it still says the same thing for some weird reason.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when i imported the **Google_Play_Services_lib** to eclipse without checking the option of **Copy Project to Workspace**.See the picture
[image]

Also check my [blogPost](http://mzubair.com/solving-the-problemserrors-of-google-maps-api-v2/) i have tried to explain the problems

Answer (score 0):

If you're on the SDK tools v17 that came out after Google I/O, check if any of these help here:

http://xrigau.wordpress.com/2012/03/22/fix-some-problems-with-libraries-in-the-adt-17-plugin-10/

http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17