# Android Maps V2 App Crashing

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have made an app that uses Google Android Maps API V2 and I have followed every step in the guide provided by Google but it doesn't work unfortunely and it crashes every time I try to start it up. So I'm wondering what is the problem?

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.android.maptest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

**Maptest Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.maptest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
    <permission
        android:name="com.android.maptest.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.maptest.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
        android:debuggable="true" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.android.maptest.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="api_key" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Logcat**

```
03-12 09:46:13.150: D/AndroidRuntime(1547): Shutting down VM

03-12 09:46:13.150: W/dalvikvm(1547): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x410e22a0)

03-12 09:46:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1547): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

03-12 09:46:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1547): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.maptest/com.android.maptest.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment

03-12 09:46:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1547):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)

03-12 09:46:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1547):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)

03-12 09:46:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1547):     at
```

android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)

```
03-12 09:46:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1547):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)

03-12 09:46:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1547):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

03-12 09:46:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1547):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

03-12 09:46:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1547):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)

03-12 09:46:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1547):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

03-12 09:46:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1547):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

03-12 09:46:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1547):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)

03-12 09:46:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1547):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)

03-12 09:46:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1547):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

03-12 09:46:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1547): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment

03-12 09:46:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1547):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)

03-12 09:46:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1547):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)

03-12 09:46:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1547):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)

03-12 09:46:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1547):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)

03-12 09:46:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1547):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:308)

03-12 09:46:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1547):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1924)

03-12 09:46:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1547):     at com.android.maptest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)

03-12 09:46:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1547):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)

03-12 09:46:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1547):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)

03-12 09:46:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1547):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)

03-12 09:46:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1547):     ... 11 more

03-12 09:46:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1547): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public

03-12 09:46:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1547):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:584)

03-12 09:46:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1547):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:552)

03-12 09:46:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1547):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4849)

03-12 09:46:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1547):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)

03-12 09:46:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1547):     ... 20 more

03-12 09:46:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1547): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment

03-12 09:46:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1547):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)

03-12 09:46:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1547):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)

03-12 09:46:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1547):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)

03-12 09:46:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1547):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:574)

03-12 09:46:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1547):     ... 23 more

03-12 09:51:21.560: I/Process(1547): Sending signal. PID: 1547 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Have you added google play service as a library project to you current project?

Comment: Your questions are all same

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226429/android-maps-app-not-finding-the-correct-mapview http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15204790/android-maps-v2-application-crashes-on-android-phone http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15192334/android-maps-v2-applicati

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you didn't add the Google Play Services library to your project.

It's located at `{Android SDK}\extras\google\google_play_services`

Add it as Android Library Project to Eclipse and then add it to your project.

Answer (score 0):

Here a blog post I wrote on how to integrate Google Maps into you application:

[Creating Google Map Application](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

From your error it look like you did not perform correctly steps 2-3 of the blog guide,
for adding Google Play services library into your application.

If you follow carefully the steps written in the guide you will end up with the end result you can see at the end of the post.

Comment: Yes I have, I've already imported(properties) it added imported(android tools) it again, I have Google Play Services installed and I'm using my phone(Galaxy S3) as an emulator and yet I get the this same crash. Thanks for responing btw.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that you have already get [`Google Maps Android API v2`](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) key and have `Google Play services`. If you not have already installed it then please follow below steps to solve this problem_

- Step 1. you can found it in `Android SDK Manager` under `Extras` tick check box of -Google Play services install it and after complete installation, restart your Eclipse.
- Step 2. Add library named_ `google-play-services_lib` found under the `extras` folder of your Android SDK setup folder to your Android project_

Path of google service lib_

```
{Your_Android_SDK_direct}\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib 

Ex. Location of this lib on My system_ 
C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib
```

I hope this will solve your ploblem.

Answer (score 0):

For me adding:

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
```

And changing the xml to

```
    <fragment
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"  />
```

resolved the problem. I hope you resolve it too!